# What's "the catch" in this question?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I am solving old exam questions and I came across this question:

> Let $\langle A_n \mid n < \omega\rangle$ disjoint sets such that $\bigcup_{n < \omega}A_n = \mathbb{R}$. Prove that there exists $n < \omega$ such that $|A_n| = |\mathbb{R}|$

It seems too easy - if the statement is false, then the cardinality of $\bigcup_{n < \omega}A_n$ is at most $\aleph_0$, which is less than $2^{\aleph_0}$, which is the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to appeal to the fact that $\kappa<\kappa^{cf(\kappa)}$. It follows that $cf(2^\omega)>\omega$, and the result is an easy corollary.

Comment: It also doesn't seem to matter whether the $A_n$'s are disjoint.

Comment: @user104955 That's what the question say...

Comment: Yep, but I'm claiming (tentatively) that the theorem would still be true if we weakened the antecedent by dropping the disjointness requirement.

Comment: (Your version is true if you assume the sets $A_n$ to be Borel.)

Comment: @Andres: Or even analytic (and if you think about it some more, co-analytic as well, although now they don't have to be countable anymore). :-)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo which version do you have in mind? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @user104955 If a countable union of Borel sets equals $\mathbb R$, then one of the sets must have the same size as $\mathbb R$; that they are disjoint is irrelevant. (Asaf mentioned analytic sets. If a countable union of disjoint analytic sets is $\mathbb R$, then the sets are actually Borel, and we are in the previous case.)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: I see. But if I was right that the theorem would hold (in ZFC) without disjointness, it would be trivial that it holds for Borel sets - it holds for any subsets of R whatsoever! So, was I wrong in thinking that?

Comment: @user104955 Yes, your version is correct. I was actually referring to the "version" hidden in the proof by the OP, where they argue that the cardinality of the union is either countable or $|\mathbb R|$.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo. Ah, I see. Thanks, Andres!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't assume that all the sets are countable. I mean, $\aleph_\omega$ is uncountable and can be written as a countable union of smaller sets.

The point is to use [König's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_%28set_theory%29), and prove that can't be true. That is, $\operatorname{cf}(2^{\aleph_0})>\aleph_0$.

As Arthur points out, this is false without the axiom of choice, as it is consistent that the real numbers are a countable union of countable sets.

Answer (score 10):

What you are missing is that the cardinal number $|\mathbb R|=2^{\aleph_0}$ is not necessarily equal to $\aleph_1$. How do you know that $2^{\aleph_0}$ is not equal to $\aleph_\omega$? It's not, but that's the point of that old exam question. The assumption that $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$ is called the [continuum hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis).

Comment: Where did I assume that $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_1$?

Comment: It looks like you assumed that $|A_n|\lt|\mathbb R|$ implies $|A_n|\le\aleph_0$, which is more or less the same thing as assuming $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$, at least if you're working in ZFC. If that's not what you assumed, how did you get the cardinality of that union to be at most $\aleph_0$?

Comment: Ok, I understand what you're saying, thanks :)